# Frozen processes not listed in **top**

Tags: linux, opensuse, top, freeze

Sometimes, processes froze without even appearing on the top terminal. This happens quite much with Adobe pdf reader to me, but also other processes. What can I do when this happens?
I can not find any related PID in the **top** screen.

EDIT: I want to kill the frozen process without rebooting.

Comment: What do you want to do? Just find the PID to kill the process?

Comment: @iñakimurillo, I want to kill the frozen process.

Comment: Is the issue that the processes freeze, or that you can't find the in the process list?

Comment: @Py-ser Have you tried with `ps aux`?

Comment: @roaima, actually both, but the priority is to kill the process.

Comment: @iñakimurillo, what is ps?

Comment: @Py-ser It's a linux command which reports a snapshot of the current processes.

Comment: @iñakimurillo, yes, it worked indeed! If you put it like an answer I can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Try `xkill`. Anyway, your question should be edited because it is not clear, many comments were needed before we could understand what you meant. Also, you can very probably find an answer to your question elsewhere. I'm sure there are already plenty of websites explaining "how to kill an application" on the web. This one is probably redundant.

Comment: I think the EDIT is super clear. I googled a lot of how to kill process that are not identified by TOP command on terminal. I wanted to solve the issue as soon as possible, and asking here was the last chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute in a terminal to list a snapshot of the current processes:

```
ps aux
```

If you want to filter by name, type:

```
ps aux | grep name_to_filter
```